# Excel VBA - Value of a field to Number

Tags: vba, excel

My quote generator creates an Excel document and I want to run a macro on it to just keep it's calculations. For some reason it says 'Number stored as text' when there are numbers. How can I change them to the number format using the macro? I have found out if I click once in the formula bar, the problem is solved too.

The code below is what I have now, but it won't solve the error.

```
Range("A1:A" & LastRow).Select
Selection.NumberFormat = "0"
```

Column A contains an amount (1, 2, 3, etc). I have another column with the same problem, but this contains a currency in € and has 2 decimal places.

```
Range("I1:I" & LastRow).Select
Selection.NumberFormat = "0.00"
```

[image]

Thanks for your help! :)

**Extra shoutout to Siddharth who helped me complete this complete issue.**

Comment: possible duplicate of [Excel: How to force cell evaluation](http://superuser.com/questions/299437/excel-how-to-force-cell-evaluation)

Comment: Going to try your thread Serg, I didn't find that when I was browsing for possible solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tom,

There are 3 ways to solve this

**1**) Go Back to your quote generator and see how it is saving the data to Excel Sheet and amend the code there

**2**) **Manually**: Highlight the Range and click on the exclamation mark next to the Green Triangle and click on "Convert to Number" See snapshot

[image]

**3**) Use this code.

```
Sub Sample()
Dim LastRow As Long, i As Long

LastRow = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A" & LastRow).NumberFormat = "0"

For i = 1 To LastRow
    If Val(Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & i).Value) <> 0 Then _
    Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & i).Formula = _
    Val(Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & i).Value)
Next i

Dim temp As Double

LastRow = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("I" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

Sheets("Sheet1").Range("I1:I" & LastRow).NumberFormat = "\$#,##0.00"

For i = 1 To LastRow
    If Val(Sheets("Sheet1").Range("I" & i).Value) <> 0 Then
    temp = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("I" & i).Value
    Sheets("Sheet1").Range("I" & i).ClearContents
    Sheets("Sheet1").Range("I" & i).Value = temp
    End If
Next i
End Sub
```

**FOLLOW UP**

Before and After snapshot attached

[image]

**MORE FOLLOW UP (IMPORTANT)**

If you have different regional settings then you will have to take care of them appropriately.

For Example Dutch Belgium you have to use "," for a decimal. Please see snapshot.

[image]

Comment: No I am not copying and pasting. I am exactly doing what you did manually. "I have found out if I click once in the formula bar, the problem is solved too". Try the code. I have tested it :)

Comment: @Tom: Uploaded a snapshot. "Check Follow Up"

Comment: @Tom: You will then have to amend the range. My Code example just takes Col A into account :) Can you post a snapshot how your data looks like?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8057/discussion-between-siddharth-rout-and-tom)

Comment: Amazing VBA PRO! His code also includes an empty field handler. Helped me out a few times now.

Answer (score 2):

Try this different ways:-

**Way 1**

```
Selection.NumberFormat = "General"
```

**Way 2**

```
vStr = "1000.5"

intNum = CInt(vStr)
```

**Way 3**

***Convert Text to Numbers With VBA***
If you frequently convert text to numbers, you can use a macro. 
Add a button to an existing toolbar, and attach the macro to that button. Then, select the cells, and click the toolbar button.

```
Sub ConvertToNumbers() 
  Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell) _
    .Offset(1, 1).Copy
  Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, _
     Operation:=xlPasteSpecialOperationAdd
  With Selection
     .VerticalAlignment = xlTop
     .WrapText = False
  End With
  Selection.EntireColumn.AutoFit
End Sub
```

Comment: So if I add Way 3 to my macro, it should do it too?

Comment: @Siva Charan: Siva that code will not solve the problem. Did you try your code before posting? :)